# TSConfig target es3 set but still system.register is used. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-3

I am developing a website using Typescript and try to avoid ECMASCRIPT > ES5 because the website that I develop is meant to run on an Opera 11 browser. For this, I try to set the `compilerOptions` - `target` in `tsconfig.json` to a low version, in this scenario to `ES3`.

Initially the following error popped up:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined

Which I fixed by including the file I downloaded from https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs.

Is it true that system.register should not be generated?

Let me know if something is not clear. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How exactly did you include `systemjs` in your page(s)?

Comment: I downloaded the minified github files `s.min.js` and `system.min.js` and included those in html script tags, but I think indeed something went wrong with this!

Comment: You can use the browser "Network" developer tab to see whether an attempt is made to load the library and whether the attempt succeeds. That's almost certainly where the problem lies.

Comment: To be more clear, it is not the main problem that `system.` is not known, but more that the typescript library generated this code, causing me to solve the issue. I wonder if it is expected behaviour

Comment: As far as I know, the whole reason `systemjs` exists is to support modules in old environments. If the TypeScript transpilation is producing the problematic code, I think it's safe to assume that it expects `System` to be defined by the import of `systemjs`.

Comment: Can you maybe try to help me in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208129/compiling-typescript-to-javascript?

Comment: I'm really not familiar with TypeScript enough to help with specifics. (If I were I may have been able to supply a real answer.)

Comment: Also: the github systemjs source code does not work with ES3. There are `let` and `const` definition in the file.